# On fixing the issue with ytick alignment in groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots, ticks

I am experiencing some issues while trying to have a common y axis scale as well as ticks. I tried some solutions like `every plot/.style` to ensure the range of the axes over the groupplot is the same but the position of the ticks seem to vary for each plot thereby leading to some misinterpretation of data. Besides, the tick marks on both x and y axes are interfering with the curves in the plot. Could you please help me fix this issue with the ticks? Here is the code.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every mark/.append style={mark size=.7pt}]
    \begin{groupplot}[scale=0.36, group style={
       group name=relcost, group size = 3 by 1, horizontal sep=1cm, %group size=3 by 4
       xlabels at=edge bottom, ylabels at=edge left, yticklabels at=edge left, every plot/.style={
                                        ymin=0,
                                        ymax=750000,
                                        enlargelimits=true
                                 }},
       xmin=0,xmax=15,
       %ymin=0,
       ymode = log,
       %log ticks with fixed point,
       %scaled y ticks=real:1e3,
       %ytick={1, 1e+3},
       xlabel={Capacity factor},
       %ytick={0, 10, 100},
       %xticklabels=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$,
       %yticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$,
       y post scale=0.36,
       ylabel={System costs},legend columns=-1,
       legend style={font=\small},
       % x tick scale label style={
    %at={(0.95,0)},yshift=-1.5em,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt
 % },
  %y tick scale label style={
   % at={(-0.05,0.99)},anchor=east,inner sep=0pt,
 % },
  %scale ticks above exponent={2},
  %scaled y ticks=false
  ]
    \nextgroupplot[title=\textsc{C-RAN}, legend to name=unnamed]

        % Low-load scenarios
    \addplot+ [black, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=grenadier!30}] coordinates {
            (0.0, 750007.1040631207)
            (3.0, 120007.1040631207)
            (6.0, 20007.104063120714)
            (9.0, 7.104063120713099)
            (12.0, 7.104063120713099)
            (15.0, 7.104063120713099)
    };
    \addplot+ [cyan, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=saffron!30}] coordinates {
            (0.0, 750173.6040631207)
            (3.0, 120173.6040631207)
            (6.0, 20173.604063120714)
            (9.0, 173.6040631207131)
            (12.0, 173.6040631207131)
            (15.0, 173.6040631207131)
    };  
    % High load
    \addplot+ [magenta, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=grenadier!30}] coordinates {  
            (0.0, 750340.1040631207)
            (3.0, 120340.1040631207)
            (6.0, 20340.104063120714)
            (9.0, 340.10406312071314)
            (12.0, 340.10406312071314)
            (15.0, 340.10406312071314)
        };  
    
%   \addplot+ [thin, saffron, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=saffron!30}] coordinates {  
%            (0, 3.8633)
%            (10, 3.6740000000000004)
%            (20, 3.6188)
%            (30, 3.5742999999999996)
%            (40, 3.5340999999999996)
%            (50, 3.4966)
%       };
    \nextgroupplot[title=\textsc{D-RAN}, legend to name=unnamed]
        
                % Low-load scenarios
    \addplot+ [black, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=grenadier!30}] coordinates {
            (0.0, 723699.4500521545)
            (3.0, 3699.4500521545033)
            (6.0, 3699.4500521545033)
            (9.0, 3699.4500521545033)
            (12.0, 3699.4500521545033)
            (15.0, 3699.4500521545033)
    };
    \addplot+ [cyan, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=saffron!30}] coordinates {
            (0.0, 723745.9702908196)
            (3.0, 3745.3708261968736)
            (6.0, 3745.3708261968736)
            (9.0, 3745.3708261968736)
            (12.0, 3745.3708261968736)
            (15.0, 3745.3708261968736)
    };  
    % High load
    \addplot+ [magenta, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=grenadier!30}] coordinates {  
            (0.0, 723792.4905294848)
            (3.0, 3791.291600239243)
            (6.0, 3791.291600239243)
            (9.0, 3791.291600239243)
            (12.0, 3791.291600239243)
            (15.0, 3791.291600239243)
        };  
    
%   \addplot+ [thin, saffron, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=saffron!30}] coordinates {  
%             (0, 1.5581)
%            (10, 1.4588999999999999)
%            (20, 1.4384)
%            (30, 1.4215)
%            (40, 1.4069)
%            (50, 1.3936)
%       };
        \nextgroupplot[title=\textsc{f-RAN}, legend to name=unnamed]
    
    % High load
    \addplot+ [black, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=grenadier!30}] coordinates {    
            (0.0, 720009.7601891027)
            (3.0, 27.482156029028516)
            (6.0, 8.98111126865991)
            (9.0, 7.092207390984598)
            (12.0, 7.092207390984598)
            (15.0, 7.092207390984598)
        };  \addlegendentry{Cost factor (0)}
    
    \addplot+ [cyan, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=saffron!30}] coordinates {   
            (0.0, 720135.5307859082)
            (3.0, 143.61324740819705)
            (6.0, 135.5307859083099)
            (9.0, 135.5307859083099)
            (12.0, 135.5307859083099)
            (15.0, 135.5307859083099)
        }; \addlegendentry{Cost factor (0.6)}
        
        
        % Low-load
    \addplot+ [magenta, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=grenadier!30}] coordinates {
            (0.0, 720227.3887317348)
            (3.0, 232.75047401100414)
            (6.0, 227.38873173479826)
            (9.0, 227.38873173479826)
            (12.0, 227.38873173479826)
            (15.0, 227.38873173479826)
    }; \addlegendentry{Cost factor (1.2)}
%   \addplot+ [thin, dashed, saffron, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=saffron!30}] coordinates {
%            (0, 0.5511)
%            (10, 0.41609999999999997)
%            (20, 0.3845)
%            (30, 0.3554)
%            (40, 0.333)
%            (50, 0.3139)
%   };  
    
    \end{groupplot}
    \node at (relcost c2r1.south) [inner sep=0pt, anchor=north, yshift=-7ex] {\ref{unnamed}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It's always appreciated if you make complete examples, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, containing all the necessary bitsm but not more, so that it can be copied and compiled without making any changes. For example, having to figure out things like non-standard colour names (like `grenadier`) is perhaps a small thing, but it's a bit annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axis limits are not plot options, so they don't belong in `every plot`. And neither `every plot` nor axis limits should be inside the `group style` I think.

But you already have `xmin` and `xmax` in the right place, so just add `ymin` and `ymax` right after those. Of course, `ymin=0` doesn't work for a logarithmic axis, but `ymin=1` seems fine. You can use `ytickten={0,2,4,6}` to get ticks at 1e0, 1e2, 1e4 and 1e6.

In this example I used red and blue instead of your custom colours.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every mark/.append style={mark size=.7pt}]
    \begin{groupplot}[
       scale=0.36,
       group style={
          group name=relcost,
          group size = 3 by 1,
          horizontal sep=1cm, %group size=3 by 4
          xlabels at=edge bottom,
          ylabels at=edge left,
          yticklabels at=edge left
       },
       ymode = log,       
       xmin=0,xmax=15,
       ymin=1,
       ymax=1e7,
       ytickten={0,2,4,6},
       xlabel={Capacity factor},
       y post scale=0.36,
       ylabel={System costs},legend columns=-1,
       legend style={font=\small},
  ]
    \nextgroupplot[title=\textsc{C-RAN}, legend to name=unnamed]

        % Low-load scenarios
    \addplot+ [black, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=blue!30}] coordinates {
            (0.0, 750007.1040631207)
            (3.0, 120007.1040631207)
            (6.0, 20007.104063120714)
            (9.0, 7.104063120713099)
            (12.0, 7.104063120713099)
            (15.0, 7.104063120713099)
    };
    \addplot+ [cyan, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=red!30}] coordinates {
            (0.0, 750173.6040631207)
            (3.0, 120173.6040631207)
            (6.0, 20173.604063120714)
            (9.0, 173.6040631207131)
            (12.0, 173.6040631207131)
            (15.0, 173.6040631207131)
    };  
    % High load
    \addplot+ [magenta, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=blue!30}] coordinates {  
            (0.0, 750340.1040631207)
            (3.0, 120340.1040631207)
            (6.0, 20340.104063120714)
            (9.0, 340.10406312071314)
            (12.0, 340.10406312071314)
            (15.0, 340.10406312071314)
        };  
    
%   \addplot+ [thin, red, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=red!30}] coordinates {  
%            (0, 3.8633)
%            (10, 3.6740000000000004)
%            (20, 3.6188)
%            (30, 3.5742999999999996)
%            (40, 3.5340999999999996)
%            (50, 3.4966)
%       };
    \nextgroupplot[title=\textsc{D-RAN}, legend to name=unnamed]
        
                % Low-load scenarios
    \addplot+ [black, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=blue!30}] coordinates {
            (0.0, 723699.4500521545)
            (3.0, 3699.4500521545033)
            (6.0, 3699.4500521545033)
            (9.0, 3699.4500521545033)
            (12.0, 3699.4500521545033)
            (15.0, 3699.4500521545033)
    };
    \addplot+ [cyan, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=red!30}] coordinates {
            (0.0, 723745.9702908196)
            (3.0, 3745.3708261968736)
            (6.0, 3745.3708261968736)
            (9.0, 3745.3708261968736)
            (12.0, 3745.3708261968736)
            (15.0, 3745.3708261968736)
    };  
    % High load
    \addplot+ [magenta, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=blue!30}] coordinates {  
            (0.0, 723792.4905294848)
            (3.0, 3791.291600239243)
            (6.0, 3791.291600239243)
            (9.0, 3791.291600239243)
            (12.0, 3791.291600239243)
            (15.0, 3791.291600239243)
        };  
    
%   \addplot+ [thin, red, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=red!30}] coordinates {  
%             (0, 1.5581)
%            (10, 1.4588999999999999)
%            (20, 1.4384)
%            (30, 1.4215)
%            (40, 1.4069)
%            (50, 1.3936)
%       };
        \nextgroupplot[title=\textsc{f-RAN}, legend to name=unnamed]
    
    % High load
    \addplot+ [black, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=blue!30}] coordinates {    
            (0.0, 720009.7601891027)
            (3.0, 27.482156029028516)
            (6.0, 8.98111126865991)
            (9.0, 7.092207390984598)
            (12.0, 7.092207390984598)
            (15.0, 7.092207390984598)
        };  \addlegendentry{Cost factor (0)}
    
    \addplot+ [cyan, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=red!30}] coordinates {   
            (0.0, 720135.5307859082)
            (3.0, 143.61324740819705)
            (6.0, 135.5307859083099)
            (9.0, 135.5307859083099)
            (12.0, 135.5307859083099)
            (15.0, 135.5307859083099)
        }; \addlegendentry{Cost factor (0.6)}
        
        
        % Low-load
    \addplot+ [magenta, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=blue!30}] coordinates {
            (0.0, 720227.3887317348)
            (3.0, 232.75047401100414)
            (6.0, 227.38873173479826)
            (9.0, 227.38873173479826)
            (12.0, 227.38873173479826)
            (15.0, 227.38873173479826)
    }; \addlegendentry{Cost factor (1.2)}
%   \addplot+ [thin, dashed, red, mark=square, mark options={scale=.3, fill=red!30}] coordinates {
%            (0, 0.5511)
%            (10, 0.41609999999999997)
%            (20, 0.3845)
%            (30, 0.3554)
%            (40, 0.333)
%            (50, 0.3139)
%   };  
    
    \end{groupplot}
    \node at (relcost c2r1.south) [inner sep=0pt, anchor=north, yshift=-7ex] {\ref{unnamed}};
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Torbjorn. I had it all messed up earlier with the labelling and the ticks.